# Python counter part of wblinv in matlab

Tags: python, scipy, weibull

I am trying to convert a matlab code into python code.
What I am stuck into is inverse weibull function part.
So, matlab code goes as follows:

```
p = 0.9978
scale_param = 3.5666
shape_param = 0.4936
wblinv(p, scale_param, shape_param)
```

wblinv gives a value corresponding a quantile, p of cdf and the result from above gives 139.9775.

I searched and found scipy provides weibull distribution functions.
I guess scipy.stats.invweibull.cdf function would do the same operation. but the result is quite different.

```
from scipy import stats
p = 0.9978
scale_param = 3.5666
shape_param = 0.4936
stats.invweibull.cdf(p, shape_param, scale=scale_param)
```

it gives abt. 0.153312

Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matlab function [`wblinv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/wblinv.html) computes the inverse cumulative distribution function for a [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution).  The corresponding distribution in scipy that you want is [`scipy.stats.weibull_min`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html), and the method to compute the inverse of the CDF (also known as the *percent point function* or the [*quantile function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function)) is `scipy.stats.weibull_min.ppf`.  The distribution [`scipy.stats.invweibull`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invweibull.html) is a different probability distribution.

For example,

```
In [10]: from scipy import stats

In [11]: p = 0.9978

In [12]: scale_param = 3.5666

In [13]: shape_param = 0.4936

In [14]: stats.weibull_min.ppf(p, shape_param, scale=scale_param)
Out[14]: 139.97751836430132
```